# Getting Error ,when I run testng from terminal

Tags: testng

```
TestingSuite
Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
```

Below is the command, I am using on ubuntu machine.

java -cp "testng jar file path:path of class files" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml

```
java -cp "/home/user/Documents/eclipse/plugins/org.testng.eclipse_6.11.0.201703011520/lib/*:/home/user/Documents/APPIUMWorkSpace/EOneMobile/target/classes/" org.testng.TestNG /home/user/Documents/APPIUMWorkSpace/EOneMobile/testng.xml
```

Suite xml file that was used

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="TestingSuite" parallel="none" verbose="1">
    <test name="Test1">
        <classes>
            <class name="testcases.TC002_Loginnative"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: my xml file is<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="TestingSuite" parallel="none" verbose="1">
  <test name="Test1">
    <classes>
      <class name="testcases.TC002_Loginnative"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>

Comment: Can you try bumping your verbosity level to 3 or more via the attribute `verbose` and share the output here ?